# Stratified grouped 5 fold cross validation issue

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have clinical data, already preprocessed (ECG and PCG) and I want to implement a stratified grouped 5-fold cross-validation, where I have one split/fold for testing, 1 split/fold for validation, and 3 splits/folds for training. This is a binary classification task where I use a multimodal deep learning neural network (1D-CNN for ECG and 2D-CNN for PCG then flatten). It must be grouped because each patient has more than one signal of the same type, and I want to classify by patient. I have done already a good amount, I just don't know how to "say" inside the for loop that 1 of the folds is for validation, as I have never seen a 5 fold cross validation with these characteristics (normally 4 folds for training and one for test). How do I accomplish that?

Following is a part of the code.

Just to clarify, I dont want to use `validation_split=0.2` in `model.fit`, but I want to give one of the folds as the validation data.

```
# Define the number of folds
n_folds = 5

# Define the batch size
batch_size = 32

# Define the number of epochs
n_epochs = 300

# Initialize the cross-validator

sgkf = StratifiedGroupKFold(n_splits=n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=32)

# Perform cross-validation

for fold, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(sgkf.split(X=ecg_final_array, y=patient_labels, groups=patient_names)):
print(f"Fold {fold + 1}")

    # Split the data into training and testing sets
    ecg_train, y_train, train_patients = ecg_final_array[train_index], patient_labels[train_index], patient_names[train_index]
    ecg_test, y_test, test_patients = ecg_final_array[test_index], patient_labels[test_index], patient_names[test_index]
    
    pcg_train, _, _ = pcg_final_array[train_index], _, _
    pcg_test, _, _ = pcg_final_array[test_index], _, _
    
    # Create the model
    model = combined_model
    
    # Fit the model on the training data
    history = model.fit(x=[pcg_train, ecg_train], y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=n_epochs,
                       validation_split=0.2, class_weight=class_weights, verbose=1)
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ . Please **remove** all the code that is irrelevant to your actual question (prints, plots, saving etc) - code here is supposed to be **minimal**.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it is my first question here!

Comment: Oh, you may have removed too much: keep some (minimized) definition of the model (I hadn't realized it was keras).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works out of the box, because in each output from `split` you get the train indices without information about which fold they came from. You'd have to peek at the later splits to find that out.  And that might be the easiest way to accomplish what you're after: just preform the loop, saving the test indices for each split, then build up your cv-loop manually using those.

In keras, I think you can then use `validation_data` instead of `validation_split`.